# Use MATCH to dynamically generate a cell reference for a formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet containing a list of candidates and scores in different topics.

For example candidate 01 scored 1,2,3,4 in areas A,B,C,D respectively.

```
   a   b  c  d  e
1  ID  A  B  C  D
2  01  1  2  3  4
3  02  2  4  5  6
4  03  3  3  7  9
```

I am trying to create a dashboard with an overview of data from different areas and I would like to produce a summary of the number of times has achieved each score from 1 - 9 in all possible topics.

```
a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k
1   ID  #9  #8  #7  #6  #5  #4  #3  #2  #1
2   03  1   0   1   0   0   0   2   0   0
3   01  0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1
4   02  0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0
```

It's straightforward enough to use a countif =COUNTIF(scores!c2:c,9) etc in each cell but I cannot guarantee the position of the candidate in the dashboard sheet therefore some form of lookup is required.

=MATCH(B2,scores!A1:E,0) used in dashboard will retrieve for me the position of candidate 03 in scores as 2.

If I could then insert that value into my countif formula I would be able to dynamically assign the required row position for my countif cell reference but I cannot work out how to or even if this is possible.

(I did consider doing this as a query but as the data spans rows rather than columns I cannot see how this would work either).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
[image]

I use here index and match formulas to get right row from the input table.
Then I use frequency function to count number of occurences.

I deal with order of rows using sort formula, but it is not necessary.

All the formulas and working example are available here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mtjHq1OCU3zgn3P9Ykm0M1EOlbjWkKI-G7Z1XN5t6Qw/copy

Comment: Brilliant solution!